# Does exporting a template in MSVC actually do any good?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, stl

When you create a struct in your public interface in MSVC that contains a templated data member, you will get a warning at compile time.

One solution is to export the templated type in your DLL (see [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q168958/) KB article).

I'm asking this question because I'm at a loss as to why you would want to export the type?

1. If you do not export it, the .hpp files have enough information to generate the type on their own.
2. If it is a standard library type and you have 2 or more dll's each potentially linking to a different version of the standard library you now have multiple binary versions of the same types in your code.

What is the point? Case #1 may cause crashes at runtime if there are actually two different versions that the compiler thinks are the same, but #2 could just fail to load due to missing symbols?

Am I completely off base here? In my opinion the best option is to just ignore the warnings from MSVC.

EDIT: No one has pointed this out yet, but I do know and understand that if you have statics in your templates and you want those statics to be shared across all uses of your DLL inside of a single application: you must, in that case, export the template instantiation. This is critical in the case of singleton like objects and loggers and such.

Comment: we disable that warning here, and never got problems. Might be just luck tough.

Comment: Ultimately, disabling the warning is the route we went with as well.

Answer (score 1):

`#2` is instant death. If you want to use Standard types in a DLL interface, you *must* guarantee that the using code is a) dynamically linked to the same CRT DLLs, and b) compiled with the same headers.

`#1` exists because you cannot guarantee that the called code has the same as you- for example, specializations and such. There's nothing wrong with this, IF you wrote the class yourself and guarantee that the client and DLL see exactly the same class.

Comment: So does that mean you are agreeing with my assessment that disabling the warnings is the only real answer? Either you have the same versions and everything works, or you do not have the same version and you either 1) crash or 2) cannot interoperate?

Comment: @lefticus: The warnings should not be disabled in general- they are important. You should disable them on a type by type basis, that is, only for types you know are defined in their entirety in a shared header.

Comment: I guess I should clarify that I'm referring specifically to standard library types. Those which are not fully implemented in the header and you have no real control over. The question is almost moot however, since the KB article I linked to explicitly says that the only type that's possible to export is std::vector.

Comment: @lefticus: In that case, you should leave the warnings intact, as they are accurately warning you that you're doing something very wrong- unless you stipulate the conditions I mentioned in `#2`.